# tableau - aggregate metric calculation - countd(unique id) / email sent if email name = X

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I'm working in tableau and trying to create an aggregate table calculation.

GOAL: I'd like to calculate a percentage response rate by email_name.

DATA SETS: One tab of the data set shows each individual person and what email_name they responded to.

The other tab of the data set shows aggregate metrics for each email_name.

WHAT I'VE DONE: 
I blended the two tabs together via email_name. On the left is the individual person response data (about 45k rows); I blended the email metric data from the right. I created the following table with email_name 
(2018 source), count respondents, # of emails sent with the email name.

[image]

QUESTIONS: 
1) How do I create a sum of the number of emails sent (sent) by the group "2018 source"?

2? How do I create a table calculation that gives me the response rate by line? Basically I want countd(respondents)/sent by 2018 source (email_name)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make "Sent(group)" a dimension and then it should automatically sum by "2018 Source" based on the way your table is shown. Also, I don't know why you have it grouped.
Then you should be able to have Response rate as:

```
Countd(respondents)/Sum(Sent)
```

Thanks